# How to remove an objectClass from an entry using python-ldap?

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I am using Python-LDAP module to interact with my LDAP server. How can I remove an objectClass from an entry using python-ldap? When I generated a modlist with `modlist.modifyModlist({'objectClass':'inetLocalMailRecipient},{'objectClass' : ''})` , it just generates `(1, 'objectClass', None)` which obviously doesn't seem correct. What am I doing wrong here? I want to remove one objectClass from a given entry using python ldap.

Comment: Generally, you can't change object classes on existing objects, because that would invalidate any schema checks the server did when creating the object. You'll have to delete the object and create a new one. This is a property of the server and doesn't have much to do with the client library.

Comment: @Guntram Blohm, Great answer and I figured out the same by experimenting. Can you post it as an answer so that I can go ahead and mark it as the answer to the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Guntram Blohm, it is not possible to delete object classes on existing objects because doing that would invalidate the schema checks that the server did when creating the object. So the way to do it will be to delete the object and create a new one. This is a property of the server and the client libraries cannot do anything about it.